# How to make this colour effect in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, blend-modes

[image]

Hi! I'm thinking of making a design that resembles this image. 
Do you have suggestions on how to create the colours in it?

I'm not sure if they are manually chosen or is there any other method you would use - say - colour blending mode?

Just wondering how the pros are doing it!

Comment: There are tons of methods to choose colors. Sure: manually is one, and a perfectly good one as well. Adobe Illustrator has built-in methods to suggest various color schemes as well.

Comment: I'd manually create the lines and use blend modes like you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way you do it is by doing it.

Make tests using different blend modes.

The image you provided is using Multiply as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this! :D  
I also managed to try different blending modes - colour burn seemed to work really well - it makes the colours look very bright.